# Code returning ValueError for special characters in string that do not exist

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, extract, newline

### Update:

**tFor reference, I am using Jupyter notebook to run these, if anybody might have any idea what's happening here. Title edited.**

Thank you for all the comments. As I reached out to different people I was told I forgot to pre-initialise the `string_of_six` variable, which would normally return a `NameError` (but didn't for some reason). I've also split off the `3.` from the original string so I no longer have to check for `x > 1` for each loop.

---

This snippet is from a code intended to read through a text file contain a million pi digits, then extract all six-digit consecutive numbers into a list (including non-unique patterns, and things like 789012).

```py
with open('pi_million_digits.txt', 'r') as file:
    pi_file = file.read(100)

for x in range(len(pi_file)):
    if x > 1 and x < (len(pi_file) - 5):
        string_of_six = pi_file[x:x+6]    

    cons_check = []
    for digit in string_of_six:
            cons_check.append(int(digit)) 
    print(cons_check)
```

When I run the code reading only the first 100 characters, this error appears (There are invisible `\n`s in the text file, but the first one is at over 100 characters.) :

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[84], line 20
         18         cons_check = []
         19         for digit in string_of_six:
    ---> 20                 cons_check.append(int(digit)) 
         21         print(cons_check)
         23 #     converts string into int and puts them in a list

    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Trying to figure out what is causing a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'` error.

Here are some things I've tried:

```py
with open('pi_million_digits.txt', 'r') as file:
    pi_withn = file.read(50)
    pi_file = pi_withn.replace('\n', '')
    print(file.read(50))
```

Using replace to try and replace \n with nothing gives the same error.

`print(pi_withn)` and `print(pi_file)`

Both return the following - all characters on the same line.
`3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375`

Have also opened the txt file to check. No newlines in the first 100 characters.

Comment: If you copy pasted the text manually there is a chance that there is newline in the file. I suggest downloading the file directly. Like for example 

`pi_txt_file = Path("pi_million_digits.txt")` 

`pi_txt_file.write_text(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehmatthes/pcc/master/chapter_10/pi_million_digits.txt").text)`

Comment: I am working with a downloaded file, and the newline characters that are in the file are by intention. (But again, the first one is at over 100 character) There is no newline character as can be seen in the output from print(pi_file), which prints the first 50 characters in the file.

Comment: You could use a try-except block to capture the string causing the error then examine the contents maybe using ord() on each character.

Comment: I recommend you should print the `pi_withn` right after reading it

Comment: It should produce `[2, 1, 1, 7, 0, 6]`  for 100 character and `[3, 9, 9, 3, 7, 5]` for 50 character right?

Comment: We're you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Post has been updated with information that should address most of the potential problems raised here.

Comment: Post the first 100 characters of the `pi_million_digits.txt` file here, so we can run your code against that file.  If we run it and don't get the same error, then that suggests your file actually **does** contain a newline in the first 100 characters.

Comment: Also, what the heck is an "invisible `\n`"??